# Trying to boot to USB to install Windows

Tags: windows

I need help with the bios on my computer. My computer is a Compaq Presario SR1538X. I'm trying to install a newer version of windows xp onto my computer but I don't know how to change the bios to boot from USB. The USB I'm using is actually using an sd card for the OS file. But since my motherboard can't take sd card storage more than 2GB, I have to use the USB. Any suggestions?

Comment: [HP and Compaq Desktop PCs - BIOS Setup Utility Information and Menu Options](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/bph07110) - look for "Boot Order - Select this to change the order of the devices from which the computer boots."

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is to press F9 during boot and select onboard USB as your boot device.

Second-best answer is to go into your BIOS setup menu (by pressing F10 during boot) and move the USB device to the top of the list of boot devices, then reboot with the bootable USB inserted.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the steps below to configure the boot order on most computers.**

Turn on or restart the computer.

While the display is blank, press the f10 key to enter the BIOS settings menu.
   NOTE:The BIOS settings menu is accessible by pressing the f2 or the f6 key on some computers.

Select the Advanced tab using the right and left arrow keys.

Use the up and down arrow keys to select Boot Order.

Follow the on-screen instructions to change the boot order.

**To reset the boot order to the default settings, follow the steps below.**

Turn on or restart the computer.

While the display is blank, press the f10 key to enter the BIOS settings menu.

Press the f9 key to reset the BIOS to the default settings.

Press the f10 key to save the changes and exit the BIOS settings menu.